# conversion from string to double with number greater than std::numeric_limit<double>::digits10

Tags: c++, double, type-conversion

```
std::string str = "12345679012.124678";
double back = boost::lexical_cast<double>( str );
std::string str2 =boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( back );

//here str2 is equal to str
```

Is it normal that there is no loss here (i.e final string = orignal string) even if number's significand digits is greater than `std::numeric_limit<double>::digits10` (i.e 15)?

Comment: It depends.  For 17 digits, there's likely no loss.  For more, the probability increases (but there will always be values for which there is no loss).

Comment: @]ames:maybe it's like for unsigned char where for values from 100 to 255 there is no loss even if `std::numeric_limit<char>::digits10` return 2 ?

Comment: For that particular value: yes, it's normal. Generally, see James Kanze's comment.

Comment: See http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/

Comment: @Maxim: thanks for the link, exactly the king of reading i am looking for

Comment: An easy way to see loss is to type in a number with all `9`s ([example](http://ideone.com/PM4pdh)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is normal.

`std::numeric_limit<double>::digits10` refers to a maximum amount of digits where casting is warranted not lossy.

This does not imply losses using wider numbers than the limit, only implies an increasing probability of loss.